# How do you change the Markdown preview font size in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, markdown

How do you change the Markdown preview font size in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1? The default font size is so small it's useless.

I've tried changing:

```
Preferences > Editor > Colors and Fonts > Font > Primary font
Preferences > Editor > Colors and Fonts > Font > Secondary font
Preferences > Editor > Colors and Fonts > Markdown
  (this doesn't have any font or size options)
⌘->scroll wheel
```

I can change the font size in editor windows, but I haven't found the trick for changing the Markdown preview window font.

I also use

```
Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance > Override default fonts by
```

And even that doesn't change the font size.

I'm using

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1
Build #IC-171.3780.95, built on March 20, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b13 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.3
```

Comment: IntelliJ 2022.3.3 seems to match the preview font size with whatever font size is set in the editor (for example, using ⌘+scroll wheel)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

At the moment, font size for the preview can be changed only [via custom CSS](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000065824-How-do-I-increase-the-font-size-when-viewing-a-rendered-markdown-md-file-in-WebStorm-).

```css
body {
    font-size: 80% !important;
}
```

[image: css]

Related request you can vote for to make it easier to change:

- [RUBY-19148](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-19148) Markdown rendering window does not support mouse wheel font size increase/decrease

Comment: If you are interested how the default CSS looks like, it can be found on GitHub here: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins/blob/master/markdown/resource/org/intellij/plugins/markdown/settings/default.css

Comment: @Peter 's link is broken now that the code was moved to the [Intellij Community Repo](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community). The [default CSS can now be found here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/5b626181f88c7fe8fd37fb1c6367173248441003/plugins/markdown/resource/org/intellij/plugins/markdown/settings/default.css)

Comment: That's a bit unfortunate that it's not easier. Even scrolling with mouse-wheel doesn't adjust it, even if set to adjust for codes.

Answer (score 0):

File > Settings > Search for 'preview' > Page Zoom (allows values from 0.1 to 10). If you set this to around 1.5 it works well. Use the decimal places to get it just right.

Answer (score 0):

if u have custom appearance, the markdown font must be changed within color scheme > color scheme font..