# IntelliJ - How to change Markdown preview font?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ has a feature that can let us preview Markdown code. An example is shown below:

[image: IntelliJ markdown preview]

However, the font used in the preview looks like Arial to me and it's different from the font used in GitHub. Therefore, I want to is it possible to change the preview font (not the font size, it's the font itself) and if so, where can I change it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change it via custom CSS in

`File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Markdown`

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42931052/4065598

Comment: If you're on MacOS that's IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Markdown, but otherwise works the same. With 2021.3.2, the Custom CSS section needs to be expanded, and either Load from or CSS rules selected. The body section in the link in this answer can be pasted directly in to CSS rules.