# How to adjust the font size for Markdown in IntelliJ DataSpell? (PyCharm)?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, dataspell

I'm trying to enlarge the font for the markdown displayed in the Jupyter Notebooks opened with IntelliJ DataSpell.
I have adjusted anything in the Settings Menu you can think of. But it only affects the Menu or the Editor, never the Markdown shown.

I found an old topic (below) but that does not work.

[How do you change the Markdown preview font size in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930593/how-do-you-change-the-markdown-preview-font-size-in-intellij-idea)

Has anybody another idea how to adjust the font size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regrettably, it is not available.

Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-232254 in order to increase its priority.

Answer (score 2):

To change the font size of the menus and markdown texts:

> *File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance -> Use custom font (change font) -> Apply / OK*

To change the font size of editor:

> *File -> Settings -> Editor -> Font (change font) -> Apply / OK*

To apply changes on Markdown cells, you have to either double click on the cell and run the cell again or just restart the DataSpell IDE.

[image]

Comment: Above does not affect markdown! The only way to increase: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42931052/630169